# Prompting a user for a string C# botframe work

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm currently busy designing a bot, that receives a project name and returns the status of it, however I can't get the prompting for the name to work.

Currently this is the method i'm using to prompt the user

```
[LuisIntent("ProjectInfo")]
        public async Task projectInfo(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result, IAwaitable<string> Userresult)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Enter your project name");
            var Promt = await Userresult;
            string projectName = Promt.ToString().ToLower();
            if(projectName != null)
            {
                TestInfo MI = new TestInfo();
                if(MI.FindProject(projectName.ToString()) == 0)
                {
                    await context.PostAsync($"Project Found. What do you want to know ?");
                }
                else
                {
                    await context.PostAsync($"Project Not Found.");
                }
            }
            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }
```

With this current code I'm receiving a Exception: ProjectInfo [File of type 'text/plain'].

I have tried using a prompt dialog but that didn't seem to work ether. My end goal for this is to loop and prompt the user for a new project name until "Project Found" is displayed.

I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way, if not any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Please provide your code of MessageReceived function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I've not come across your version yet but I can give you an example of a different approach.

Usually I prompt for simple texts something like this:

```
PromptDialog.Text(context, AfterPromptMethod, "Prompt text", attempts: 100);
```

Signature of AfterPromptMethod:

```
async Task AfterPromptMethod(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> userInput)
```

With this you could do your logic in the AfterPromptMethod and loop back to the prompt in messageReceived.

Comment: I literally just found a different example of this, this does what I need thanks, however the string that's captured is "Wait: Call String for TestBot.SimpleLuisDialog.AfterPromptMethod.Rest have String TestProject" - Test project is the string i typed in.

Comment: Use await to get the raw string. var inputText = await userInput;

Comment: Greetings,Sorry to bother you again. I'm trying to get it to loop back into the Task which calls the original prompt if the project name inst found, do you know how to do this ? I've tried using context.call/wait they dont seem to want to respond

Comment: 2 options: context.Wait(MessageReceived) to go back into the entry function which might contain the prompt. Or use the same PromptDialog.Text(....) line again